# (Why) does the late radiation after page time entangle with the early radiation?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-information, thermal-radiation, hawking-radiation, ads-cft

In [Jerusalem lectures by Harlow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1231) Pg. 53 it is said that

> At the beginning of the
> evaporation process the radiation that comes out is entangled with the remaining black
> hole. But eventually it must start coming out entangled with the earlier radiation,
> since eventually the final state of the radiation must be pure.

1. Why is the late radiation i.e. the radiation that comes out after the Page time entangled with the earlier radiation to purify itself instead of entangling itself with the remaining black hole?
   Is it because the black hole has a different state space?
   I found a supposed answer by [Polchinski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.04036)

> With the black hole, the internal excitations are behind the horizon, and cannot influence the state of later photons.

2. So it seems Polchinski is using causality to argue against entanglement with interior methods. But why then won't it then hold for early photons? (He does use the word "late" and we know the early modes are entangled with the interior).

Instead I would expect by Page's theorem that the remaining old black hole is maximally mixed and forms a maximally entangled pure state with the early radiation at late times, but then why isn't this mentioned in Harlow's quote?

I can understand the Page curve and its qualitative derivation as given in Harlow but not the "intuitive" description by Harlow that follows the derivation on pg. 53. How to arrive at what couples with what after the Page time from the Page curve itself?

Condensing these questions amounts to asking the titular question which can be expanded and rephrased as as:

*Do the small old black hole entangle with the early radiation or does the late radiation does and why?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic consequence of the assumption (done in pag. 47) that the black hole evaporation process is unitary. Since eventually the radiation must be be in a pure state and the black hole will evaporate, the late radiation must somehow purify the early radiation. Explaining in detail how this happen is part of solving the information paradox, on which we recently made some progress in AdS/CFT, see for instance results by Penington such as [Entanglement Wedge Reconstruction and the Information Paradox](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.08255)
.

Comment: Thanks for the last part of the answer, but I am still not able to understand why should the early radiation should be the "thing" to purify the late radiation and not the black hole itself? I know that the final radiation must be pure because of unitarity: but why should the early radiation be the purifying entity?

Comment: The late radiation purifies the early one. Because the black hole is going to evaporate completely eventually, leaving nothing behind to be entangled with. An alternative is leaving a black hole remnants behind, a small mass object with arbitrary large entanglement,  but those are generally considered suspicious since they would break quantum theories by entering into loop calculations.  See for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/0909.1038.pdf

Comment: To be fair, remnants are not completely ruled out, but they enter the quantum gravity territory. See for instance https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.8366

Comment: Is the black hole not entangled with any form of radiation after Page time, then?

Comment: It is still entangled with the early radiation emitted before the page time. After that time the emitted radiation, the late radiation, comes out engangled with the early radiation, "stealing" the entanglement from the black hole.

Comment: @Sanjana Does the answer + comments cover your question? If so please accept the question.

Comment: It does answer the question partially but I think I don't understand Polchinski's quote. What exactly does he mean by "influence"? Does he mean "entangled"---then it would be against what you (I think correctly) said. If by "influence" he means "causally relate", then why does he use the word "later" infront of photons: The interior is causally disconnected from the exterior all the time!

Comment: But yes, thank you for all the time and effort (+1)

Comment: Thanks. It would probably be suited to open another question for that, but I will answer briefly here. Polchinski there is stating the basic premise of the black hole paradox, that is the black hole is "black", all the emitted radiation is thermal and the black hole does not leave an inprint on the outgoing radiation. This is opposite to the case of a burning piece of coal, which has no horizon. But to solve the information paradox without remnants this hypothesis must be wrong somehow. It could be fuzzballs, wormholes, soft gravitons, etc, pick your favorite solution!

Comment: So Polchinski there is just stating the paradox and referring to causal influence, but I don't think he literally believes that.